# Compare the date value of an array of objects with the dates from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, data-structures

I have the folowing use case and I am stack for days.

I have an array which contains dates in a string format like the following:

```js
var rows = ["23-01-2021", "24-01-2021", "25-01-2021", "26-01-2021", "27-01-2021", "28-01-2021"]
```

I have also a data structure with the working days for each employee

```js
var schedule = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Chandler Bing",
    times: [

      {
        start: "9.00",
        end: "17.00",
        date: "25-01-2021"
      },
      {
        start: "9.00",
        end: "17.00",
        date: "26-01-2021"
      },


      {
        start: "9.00",
        end: "17.00",
        date: "28-01-2021"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Employee 2",
    times: [

      {
        start: "9.00",
        end: "17.00",
        date: "23-01-2021"
      },
      {
        start: "9.00",
        end: "17.00",
        date: "27-01-2021"
      },


      {
        start: "9.00",
        end: "17.00",
        date: "28-01-2021"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to compare the array of dates with the array of times for each employee. If dates are missing from the array of times create an object with null values... Actually I would like to end up to a data structure like the following.

```js
var schedule = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Employee 1",
  times: [{
      start: "",
      end: "",
      date: ""
    }, {
      start: "",
      end: "",
      date: ""
    },
    {
      start: "9.00",
      end: "17.00",
      date: "25-01-2021"
    },
    {
      start: "9.00",
      end: "17.00",
      date: "26-01-2021"
    },
    {
      start: "",
      end: "",
      date: ""
    },


    {
      start: "9.00",
      end: "17.00",
      date: "28-01-2020"
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "Employee 2",
  times: [

    {
      start: "",
      end: "",
      date: ""
    },
    {
      start: "",
      end: "",
      date: ""
    },
    {
      start: "",
      end: "",
      date: ""
    },
    {
      start: "",
      end: "",
      date: ""
    },
    {
      start: "9.00",
      end: "17.00",
      date: "27-01-2021"
    },
    {
      start: "9.00",
      end: "17.00",
      date: "28-01-2021"
    },
  ]
}
]]
```

I have implemented this logic until now but obviosly is not working

```js
var rows = ["23-01-2021", "24-01-2021", "25-01-2021", "26-01-2021", "27-01-2021", "28-01-2021"]
var schedule = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Chandler Bing",
  times: [{
      start: "9.00",
      end: "17.00",
      date: "25-01-2021"
    },
    {
      start: "9.00",
      end: "17.00",
      date: "26-01-2021"
    },
    {
      start: "9.00",
      end: "17.00",
      date: "28-01-2021"
    },

  ]
}]


var arr = []
var test = {};

rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
  schedule.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry.times.forEach(function(times, index) {
      console.log(row)
      if (times.date === row) {
        test = {
          start: times.start,
          end: times.end,
          date: times.date
        }
        arr.push(test)
      } else {
        test = {
          start: "",
          end: "",
          date: ""
        }
        arr.push(test);
      }
    })
  })
})
console.log(arr);
```

Every help is appreciated...

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. It is an antipattern to create empty slots when you can just process them as empty where you need to process them

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks a lot! Propably I need to find an other solution if this one does not makes sense. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map rows and have a look to `times` and take this obkject if date has the same value.

This approach features a closure over an index an needs sorted data of `schedule`'s `times` array.

```js
const
    rows = ["23-01-2021", "24-01-2021", "25-01-2021", "26-01-2021", "27-01-2021", "28-01-2021"],
    schedule = [{ id: 1, name: "Chandler Bing", times: [{ start: "9.00", end: "17.00", date: "25-01-2021" }, { start: "9.00", end: "17.00", date: "26-01-2021" }, { start: "9.00", end: "17.00", date: "28-01-2021" }] }, { id: 2, name: "Employee 2", times: [{ start: "9.00", end: "17.00", date: "23-01-2021" }, { start: "9.00", end: "17.00", date: "27-01-2021" }, { start: "9.00", end: "17.00", date: "28-01-2021" }] }],
    result = schedule.map(o => ({ ...o, times: rows.map((i => date => o.times[i]?.date === date
       ? o.times[i++]
       : { start: "", end: "", date: "" }
    )(0)) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Nina thanks for your effort...!If anybody has an es5 solution will be more appreciated because I cannot understand at all Nina's logic..